# Is there a cheat code or other way to obtain infinite candies?

Tags: candy-box-2, cheats

I've been searching everywhere for a cheat to get infinite candies, I find that candy box kind of rips me off!

So is it possible to get infinite candies?

Comment: @Frank, not really. That question is about legitimate ways to increase the candy production rate, while this one is about how to cheat the game into giving you a (theoretically) infinite amount of candies.

Comment: I don't get why this was downvoted so heavily - we allow questions about cheats here so long as they [only affect singleplayer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/489/how-do-we-stand-on-cheats-in-particularly-for-multiplayer-games) (multiplayer hacks are bad)

Answer (score 7):

You can easily get as many candies as you want by editing your savegame.

Just press the `SAVE` button (next to the `CFG` button), then click on `Get the current game as text`.

You might want to copy the save text into a text editing software to more easily edit it. Next, search for

```
number gameCandiesCurrent=x
```

and replace `x` by whatever number you wish, for instance:

```
number gameCandiesCurrent=9999999999
```

Copy the save text into the `Text load` box and click on `Load` to get all the candies you wish.

Comment: @LiamJermy. Please do not hijack existing answers. Once you've accumulated 10 reputation (it's not *that* hard, really) you can post your own answer.